# It's not in the film

Tags: word-usage

A song that was included in a trailer of a film was not a part of the film. So what should be used:

> Why isn't this song part of this film?
>
> Why isn't this song in the film?

What sounds more natural: "part of/in"?

Answer (score 1):

They're both acceptable colloquialisms (which is preferred will depend on where you're standing when you say it).  Therefore, the complete concept...

> Why was that song not included as part of the film?

Could be heard as...

> Why isn't the song part of the film?
>   Why isn't the song a part of the film?
>   Why isn't the song in the film?
>   Why was the song cut from the film?
>   Why was the song deleted from the film?